# ReactNavigator -StackNavigator how to use diffrent animation with only specific screen

Tags: react-navigation

using

"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",

"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",

```
import {
  createStackNavigator, StackViewTransitionConfigs,
} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  List:ListContainer,
  Detail:DetailContainer,
  Modal: {
    screen: ModalContainer,
    navigationOptions: {
      ...StackViewTransitionConfigs.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS,
    },
  },
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    gestureEnabled: true,
    ...StackViewTransitionConfigs.SlideFromRightIOS,
  },
});
```

All other screens open in the form of a card, and I want to open only one specific screen in modal form.

i tried

```
const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  List:ListContainer,
  Detail:DetailContainer,
  },
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    gestureEnabled: true,
    ...StackViewTransitionConfigs.SlideFromRightIOS,
  },
});
const HomeStackNavigator2 = createStackNavigator({
  Home:HomeStackNavigator,
  Modal: {
    screen: ModalContainer,
  },
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  headerMode: 'none',
});
```

The first code failed because all the arcs were opened in card format.

In the second code I tried, the screen I wanted was opened in modal form, but when I moved from modal to detail, the modal was closed.

In the first code, is it possible to open only the modal screen in modal form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way.

```
import {
  createStackNavigator, StackViewTransitionConfigs, StackViewStyleInterpolator,
} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const transitionConfigs = (props) => {
  const { scene } = props;
  const { route } = scene;
  const params = route.params || {};
  const transition = params.transition || 'forHorizontal';
  if (transition === 'forVertical') {
    return StackViewTransitionConfigs.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS;
  }
  return StackViewTransitionConfigs.SlideFromRightIOS;
};

const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  List:ListContainer,
  Detail:DetailContainer,
  Modal: {
    screen: ModalContainer,
  },
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  transitionConfig:transitionConfigs,
});
```

Change animation by sending `trasition:'forVertical'` to params when navigate.